# Routing Error :: No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/about"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, custom-routes

I am getting this error while going through the tutorial by Michael Hartl.
Section 5.3.2 (Rails routes).

Content of my **routes.rb** file is

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
   root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

My **rspec** at static_pages is successful ..I have followed every instructions but 
still getting this error while trying to access any of the pages at `

```
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/about
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/contact
```

This is the error i am getting on these pages

**Action Controller:Exception caught**

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/about"

Rails.root: /home/abhinay/rails_projects/sample_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom



  Helper     HTTP Verb  Path             Controller#Action
    Path / Url          
    root_path     GET       /                    static_pages#home
    help_path     GET      /help(.:format)   static_pages#help
    about_path    GET      /about(.:format)  static_pages#about
    contact_path  GET      /contact(.:format)    static_pages#contact
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look you do not have any routes `"/static_pages/about"`

so you got error

```
 Routing Error
 No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/about"
```

As per your routes for about page `/about` should be the url

```
 http://localhost:300/about   
 http://localhost:300/contact 
 http://localhost:300/help
```

It will acutally call your `static_pages` controller and `about` action of that controller

and from url helper of rails routes you get

For  About:

`about_path` or `about_url` should be used

For contact

`contact_path` or `contact_url`

For help

`help_path` or `help_url`

Comment: Ohh!! how silly i am..answer is always in front of me and i am just looking here and there..actually i have always pressed first letter of url like "l" in the URl bar since it automatically gives all the suggestions and by doing that i never bothered about URL..thanks a lot..problem solved!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use these:

```
http://localhost:3000/         <!-- Maps to /home -->
http://localhost:3000/help       <!-- Maps to /static_pages/help-->       
http://localhost:3000/about       <!-- Maps to /static_pages/about-->       
http://localhost:3000/contact       <!-- Maps to /static_pages/contact-->
```

Comment: thanks buddy for the answer and i really thankful that you replied to my problem..but i don't have much reputation to vote up the answer ..may be next time as i am new to this group.

Answer (score 2):

Your path to `static_pages#about` is

> /about

instead of

> /static_pages/about